# can't return one record when var_dump does show

Tags: php, yii

I can't return my model. But when I `return var_dump($model)` I can see the record. Why can't I just `return $model` then? I don't see any error, it just shows a blank section.

I have this in a widget:

```
$model = Table::model()->something1();           
 $id =Yii::app()->request->getQuery('id');

if($model==null){
    $model = new Table;
    if (isset($_POST['Table'])){
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Table'];                   
        $model->product_id = $product_id;
        $model->user_id = Yii::app()->user->user_id;
        $model->save();
    }
}else {
    $m = Table::model()->something2($id);
    //return var_dump($m[0]); I just want one record
    //I also tried just getting $model, doesn't work   
    //I just want to get the model if it's there is a record
    return $m;
}

        $this->renderFile(Yii::getPathOfAlias('app.some.path'). '/_form.php',array(
                'model' => $model,
        ));
```

And heres from my model:

```
public function something1(){
$uid = Yii::app()->user->user_id;
$id =Yii::app()->request->getQuery('id');

$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('user_id',$uid);
$criteria->compare('product_id',$id);
$criteria->limit = 1;

$record = $this->exists($criteria);
return $record;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean: $this->find($criteria) instead of "exists". That just checks if a row exists and returns a boolean, not a record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model function `something1()` returns a boolean instead of a record because you are calling `exists()` instead of `find()`.

As an alternative you can write the entire function as follows too:

```
public function something1() {
    return $this->findByAttributes(array('user_id' => Yii::app()->user->id, 
       'product_id' => Yii::app()->request->getQuery('id')));
}
```